# When does a new python session in AWS is created?

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I have a scheduled event that triggers a lambda every two minutes in certain hours. Most of the time, as it does `from file import lambda_handler`, it maintains the same python session. Namely, the global variables are kept between runs.

Every several hours(not consistently), it reinitiate a python session.
This results in a strange pattern, which I couldn't figure out the reasoning behind it. Is there?

Comment: You should **not** ever count on the lambda function saving state between runs.

Comment: True you shouldn't _count_ on this, but it's important to understand that it _can_ and does happen so you can take advantage of it and avoid potential pitfalls. So, to that same point, you should not count on the state being fresh with every invocation.

Comment: I am not strictly counting on it. But it does cause a bit of trouble. It is interesting question when should I serialize things to save state (performance considerations), as it is not too awful if it is not kept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are observing is an artifact of 'cold starts' vs 'warm starts' in AWS Lambda. When functions are invoked within a short time period of each other, they may (or may not) reuse the same working container; this is a warm start.

Warm starts help optimize execution time. In this case, global objects are re-used for optimizing things like database connections or similar actions. Cold starts start a new container entirely, which means there's no existing state in memory. Cold starts also take somewhat longer, since it has to bootstrap the runtime again.

In the following code snippet, the `CONNECTION` object is global. The handler function checks to see if `CONNECTION` was already created and, if it is, it does not attempt to create a new one. If you were to invoke such a function many times in a short period and watch the log output for such a function, you would see it reuse the connection a lot.

```
logger.info('Cold Start')
CONNECTION = None
def my_handler(event, context):
    global CONNECTION
    if CONNECTION is None:
        logger.info('Initializing Connection')
        CONNECTION = make_connection()
    else:
        logger.info('reusing existing connection!')
    with CONNECTION:
        ... # do something
```

**There is no set time period for which a warm start will occur, nor is there any guarantee that function invocations will be a warm start, even when they're called closely in time proximity.** The Lambda service tries to decide whether to keep functions warm intelligently based on invocation patterns.

In some serverless frameworks like [zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa#keeping-the-server-warm) there are configurations that invoke the function periodically (say, every 4 minutes) to attempt to keep it warm so that the next invocation of, say, a web request, will not bear the expense of a cold start.

Further reading:

https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/best-practices-for-aws-lambda-container-reuse-6ec45c74b67e

https://www.serverless.com/blog/keep-your-lambdas-warm

Comment: Thanks. It is interesting that contrary to their warm up plugin claims(it keeps it warm), my 2 minutes lambda turns cold after several hours.

Comment: Yeah. The keep-warm is a best-effort. Though, it is somewhat predictable if your invocation pattern is consistent over the lifetime of the function, as a result of how AWS _happens_ to implement this warm-start functionality. However, there are no guarantees on the AWS implementation of things on whether or not a new invocation will we a warm start or not. You may also get cold starts for other reasons like concurrent invocations or reasons we're not privy to behind the scenes, like underlying hosts being at capacity, recycled, or becoming unhealthy.